# Add job to scheduler to invoke that job automatically everyday

Tags: sql, oracle, job-scheduling, dbms-scheduler

I have a created a job which runs on everyday at 09:00:00.

Below is the snippet i have used to create a job :

```
BEGIN
            Dbms_Scheduler.create_job(
                job_name   => 'PROECSS_STATE_ARCH'
               ,job_type   => 'STORED_PROCEDURE' 
               ,job_action   => 'TEST' -- Procedure Name
               ,start_date   => SYSDATE 9:00:00
               ,repeat_interval => 'freq=DAILY'
               ,enabled   => TRUE
               ,comments   => 'job schedule for archiving process_state');
END;
```

sole purpose of this is to run a stored procedure 'TEST' on everyday at 09:00:00

how to add this job to scheduler to invoke this job automatically on everyday?
Can anyone please tell me ??

Comment: Shouldn't that be PROCESS_STATE_ARCH ?

Comment: Ya, job name is process_state_arch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `byhour` too to run the job everyday at 9 pm.

```
BEGIN
            Dbms_Scheduler.create_job(
                job_name   => 'PROECSS_STATE_ARCH'
               ,job_type   => 'STORED_PROCEDURE' 
               ,job_action   => 'TEST' -- Procedure Name
               ,start_date   => SYSDATE
               ,repeat_interval => 'freq=DAILY; byhour=9' --Added byhour
               ,enabled   => TRUE
               ,comments   => 'job schedule for archiving process_state');
END; 
/
```

To run this on your scheme, you need `CREATE JOB` privilege. Otherwise you need to run this on any other privileged user. In that case specify job_action as,

```
job_action   => '<SCHEMA_NAME>.TEST'
```

To edit the job, you have the SET_ATTRIBUTE procedure in DBMS_SCHEDULER package.

Eg:-

```
BEGIN
     DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE (
          name => 'PROECSS_STATE_ARCH',
          attribute => 'repeat_interval',
          value => 'freq=DAILY; byhour=10' --Everyday by 10 AM.
          ); 
END;
```

Comment: Thank you. Will it run daily if i execute above code snippet? Where this job will be stored if i want to edit later. Any idea ?

Comment: Yes i don't have privilege to create a job. Thank you:)

Comment: @vkreddy, Yeah, this will run everyday at 9:00 AM. I've added an example for how to edit a created job in my answer.

Comment: Job has been created Successfully. But the procedure has not executed. Plz suggest @Dba